# How to use $lookup on arrays in two different collections?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is 'company' collection data

```
{
  _id: "1",
  company: "ABC",
  addresses: [
    {
      _id: "2",
      address: "a1",
      district: "d1",
      city: "c1"
    },
    {
      _id: "3",
      address: "a2",
      district: "d2",
      city: "c2"
    },
    {
      _id: "4",
      address: "a3",
      district: "d3",
      city: "c3"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is 'product' collection data

```
{
  product: "xyz",
  companyid: "1",           //_id of record in company's collection
  addresses: ["2", "4"]    //addresses _id of record in company's collection
},
{
  product: "pqr",
  companyid: "1",
  addresses: ["3", "4"]
}
```

Now I need to get all products with company and their addresses like below

```
{
  product: "xyz",
  company: "ABC",
  addresses: [
    {
      _id: "2",
      address: "a1",
      district: "d1",
      city: "c1"
    },
    {
      _id: "4",
      address: "a3",
      district: "d3",
      city: "c3"
    }
  ]
},
{
  product: "pqr",
  companyid: "ABC",
  addresses: [
    {
      _id: "3",
      address: "a2",
      district: "d2",
      city: "c2"
    },
    {
      _id: "4",
      address: "a3",
      district: "d3",
      city: "c3"
    }
  ]
}
```

If there is array, only in products we can $unwind them and perform lookup. But in this condition there are arrays in both the collections, then how can we compare them or use $lookup to get the expected output? If there is any other alternative, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try running the following aggregate operation to get the desired result:

```
db.product.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "company",
            "localField": "companyid",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "company"
        }
    },
    { 
        "$addFields": {
            "company":  { "$arrayElemAt": ["$company", 0] }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$addFields": {            
            "addresses":  { 
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$company.addresses",
                    "as": "ad",
                    "cond": {
                        "$setIsSubset": [
                            ["$$ad._id"],
                            "$addresses"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { "$project": { "company": 0 } }
])
```

Comment: Great use of $setIsSubset.